# How do I add a CKEditor plugin from within a plugin?

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I am developing a CKEditor plugin that I would like to be vehicle to deliver multiple plugins all required for the correct editing experience. Basically I want the user to be able to include a single "the_framework" plugin, which in turn adds 10 more plugins (each a widget with toolbar button and possibly context menu) that provides the full editing support. I do not want the "plugin" configuration to be responsible for loading these plugins. It's really an all or nothing proposition in my case.

I've tried having the master plugin add external plugins with `CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal` but they don't load. I realize now this is because the `plugins` or `extraPlugins` configuration doesn't name the external plugins so `Editor.loadPlugins` never tries them. However, by the time my master plugin loads and executes `onLoad` it's already too late to change the configuration.

I'm fine with having [multiple plugin definitions in one plugin file](https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/2906), but it appears it still won't work if the editor config doesn't explicitly name them all.

How can I load a plugin from another plugin?

Answer (score 0):

After some more debugging, I have determined this to be impossible.

I realized to load the "sub-plugins" registered as externals I simply needed to call `CKEDITOR.plugins.load` with the names of the plugins after registering them. That is the same method called by the editor, however, the editor follows up with a lot of extra steps including loading language files and critical callbacks (`beforeInit`, `init`, and `afterInit`).

The `editor.js` `loadPlugins` function is where all the action occurs, but it only accepts an `Editor` argument without a list of plugins to load, because the editor's config is used for determining which plugins to load. Once the list is determined, they are all loaded in parallel. If the sub-plugins are not in this array from the beginning, even if the master plugin loads them manually later, they will never be fully initialized with an editor.

The only work-around I have come up with involves loading one extra script after loading the CKEditor source, ideally a script distributed with the master plugin. The script sets up the external sub-plugin definitions (which are actually in a local subfolder named "master_plugin/plugins") and registers an `instanceCreated` callback, which basically looks at the a new editor's config and determines if the sub-plugins need to be added to the list before the editor initializes. If any of this occurs from within a plugin, vs the extra script, it is too late and it will fail.

**UPDATE**

It was actually necessary to register a `configLoaded` listener inside the `instanceCreated` callback, because when `instanceCreated` occurs the user's config is not yet loaded into the editor. The `customConfigLoaded` event is also too early to receive the user's config, so any modifications to `plugins` or `extendedPlugins` will still be lost. Surprisingly, the `configLoaded` event is fired *after* the editor makes use of several config options (readOnly, enterMode, shiftEnterMode, tabIndex, skin, maybe others), but `plugins` is not yet touched.

The `configLoaded` event is the only hook point I could find to guarantee edits to the page-supplied config. With the `config.customConfig` option, it would be possible to listen for `customConfigLoaded` within the [editorConfig](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-method-editorConfig) function and get the full config, because CKEditor only merges the page config inside its own `customConfigLoaded` listener. (The order of operations makes this possible.)

Returning to the original goal of loading many plugins through a single plugin (add-on package), it is possible but obviously nothing intended by the design of the plugin system.